# JQuery simple add class is not working

Tags: jquery, css

```
       <div class="newstitle">
            <ul class="newstitle">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Content)
                {
                    if (item.Value != null)
                    { 
                     <li>
                            <div class="newstitle_title">@item.Key.Name</div>
                        </li>
                    }
                }
           </ul> 
  </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.newstitle li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('last');
 });
 </script>
```

I have this code, i ve been trying to run and it s breaking the css.
 [image: Broken CSS]

However, it should be like the following, please see the spacing between images:
[image]

how can i fix this? if you see there is both div and ul has the same class name.

This is what the generated html should be:

```
<div class="newstitle">
    <ul class="newstitle">
        <li>image</li>
        <li>image</li>
        <li>image</li>
        <li class="last">image</li>
        <li>image</li>
        <li>image</li>
        <li>image</li>
        <li class="last">image</li>
        <li>image</li>
        <li>image</li>
        <li>image</li>
        <li class="last">image</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

and here is the css:

```
.newstitle  {width:600px;overflow:hidden;margin:15px auto;}
.newstitle li {float:left;width:140px;height:170px;overflow:hidden;margin:0px 13px 0px 0px;display:inline;position:relative;}
.newstitle .last {float:left;width:140px;height:170px;overflow:hidden;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;display:inline;position:relative;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('li', 'ul.newstitle').filter(function() {return $(this).index()%4===0}).addClass('last');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wgXWg/2/)

Comment: And the css for what `.last` is supposed to do would be helpful too.

Comment: @JMCCreative - Yes it would, but I'm assuming it's mostly for setting margin between the images, but what images, all I see are some non rendered models?

Comment: @Darth there's got to be an simpler way to get a linebreak.

Comment: please see my edit for the what the generated html should be.thansk

Comment: So you're trying to get a new row on every fourth image, not every "odd" image, see my updated answer.

Comment: My bad, forgot the zero check, try it now ?

Comment: Thanks for the efforts dude. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $li = $('ul.newstitle li'),
            y = 0;
        for (var i=0, n = $li.length; i < n; i++) {
          if ( y++ === 3 ) {
              $($li[i]).addClass("last");
              y = 0;
          }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Hopes it helps